How to rotate a complete graph including the axes?
I have a graph from the following code:
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))

x_P = PSP_1[:,4]
y_P = PSP_1[:,5]


plt.plot(x_P,y_P, color = "red", label="Static Pressure")

plt.title("Static Pressure")
plt.legend(loc="upper right", frameon=False)
plt.ylabel("[Pa]")
plt.xlabel("[m]")
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig('STATIC_PRESSURE.jpeg',dpi=100)
plt.show()
plt.close(fig1)

which reproduces the following image:

the graph is ok and serves its purpose, but as it represents pressure on an inclined surface I think it would be more interesting to present the graph also in an inclined way.
Something like this:

Can anyone help me?

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/axisartist/demo_floating_axes.html#sphx-glr-gallery-axisartist-demo-floating-axes-py

https://github.com/rougier/scientific-visualization-book/blob/master/code/coordinates/transforms-floating-axis.py

You have already presented your graph in an inclined way, presumably by rotating a saved .png image. What is wrong with that approach?
